# Validation Block not correctly validating properties in Enterprise Library 5.0

Tags: regex, vb.net, validation, enterprise-library, enterprise-library-5

I have correctly configured validation block using Enterprise Library Configuration Console.

My app.config file looks like the following (I only show here validation section):

```
    <validation>
    <type name="XFRop.Settings" defaultRuleset="All Settings Validation Ruleset"
        assemblyName="XFRop, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
        <ruleset name="All Settings Validation Ruleset">
            <properties>
                <property name="RemoteIPAddress">
                    <validator type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Validators.RegexValidator, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                        pattern="\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b"
                        tag="RemoteIpAddress_Validator" name="Regular Expression Validator" />
                </property>
                <property name="RemotePort">
                    <validator type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Validators.RangeValidator, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                        culture="es-ES" lowerBound="0" lowerBoundType="Inclusive"
                        upperBound="65535" tag="RemotePort_Range_Validator" name="Range Validator" />
                </property>
                <property name="Culture">
                        <validator type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Validators.RegexValidator, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                            pattern="^[A-Za-z]{1,8}(-[A-Za-z0-9]{1,8})*$" tag="Culture_Validator"
                            name="Regular Expression Validator" />
                </property>
            </properties>
        </ruleset>
    </type>
</validation>
```

I have the following class in VB.NET (I will simplify my class into three properties here):

```
Public NotInheritable Class Settings

    Private Shared _RemoteIPAddress As String
    Private Shared _RemotePort As UShort
    Private Shared _Culture As String

    Public Shared Property RemoteIPAddress() As String
        Get
            Return _RemoteIPAddress
        End Get

        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _RemoteIPAddress = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Shared Property RemotePort() As UShort
        Get
            Return _RemotePort
        End Get

        Set(ByVal value As UShort)
            _RemotePort = value
        End Set
    End Property 

    Public Shared Property Culture() As String
        Get
            Return _Culture
        End Get

        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Culture = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Note that:

- RemoteIPAddress is an IPv4 address so I build the following regular
  expressions to check it:

  \b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b
- RemotePort is a property containing a port that ranges from 0-65535.
- Culture is a property containing a language culture name so I build regular expression:

  ^[A-Za-z]{1,8}(-[A-Za-z0-9]{1,8})*$

Now, when my application starts I initialize my settings class as below:

```
    Private Sub InitSettings()

        Settings.RemoteIPAddress = My.Settings.RemoteIPAddress
        Settings.RemotePort = My.Settings.RemotePort
        Settings.Culture = My.Settings.Culture

    End Sub
```

And after that I validate the settings in "Settings" class by using below validation code:

```
Public Sub Main()

    ' Initialize application settings
    Me.InitSettings()

    ' Validate current application settings
    results = Validation.Validate(New Settings)
    If results.IsValid Then
        ' Initiate Background worker thread
        Me.DoTask()
    End If

End Sub
```

I have two problems with validation:

1. Validation is returning true (results.IsValid = true) but RemoteIPAddress property contains empty string. Why validation returns true if RemoteIPAddress does not complain regular expression? It is an empty string so it should return false instead of true. Note: I have configured Regular expression validator from console with  Negated property set to the default: false.
2. results object contains the following information:

   - Count has value 0
   - IsValid has value true
   - validationResults has value Count=0
   - Expanding "Results" produces no results

It seems like validation is not being correctly applied so What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have discovered that properties cannot be marked as Shared. If so, enterprise library validation block does not work. So removing Shared from properties it seems to work. Why?

Comment: The Validation Application Block only validates instance variables (properties, fields).  If you wanted to validate shared/static variables then you could look at self validation or perhaps modifying the block to validate shared variables.  Or if you change your design to make the Settings class a singleton with instance variables then it would work with the block.